# Copying files to upgrade scipy

Tags: terminal, scipy

I have been struggling with upgrading my version of scipy from 0.13.0b1 to 0.16.0. I downloaded 0.16.0 and after much failure, realized that my python program was looking in the wrong place and finding the old version but not the new one. I modified the sys.path to include the location of the new scipy download, but this still didn't work.

So, I have tried to remove the old version of scipy from the directory holding it and copy in the new version of scipy (I could not simply remove this directory from the sys.path due to other dependancies). However, when I run the relevant command

```
sudo cp -R scipy/ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

nothing happens. There is no error message, but the new scipy does not go into the directory. Does anyone know why this is, or have an alternate solution to upgrading my scipy?

Comment: This is a very messy way to solve this. First check your `PYTHONPATH`, if it is set, you may want to unset it. Then use `pip` to install and uninstall packages. don't copy, move or delete packages manually by command line.

Comment: My PYTHONPATH seems to be unset. If I already have the new version, why would reinstalling it via pip help?

Comment: I do not understand this comment. I assume that the whole point of your question is that you still have the old version.